# Argument count error with Capistrano 3 deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

My deployment fails with this error : http://pastie.org/9494311#10,12

My problem is, I can't find where the argument count error is happening !

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it comes from `config/deploy.rb:65:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Author asked where the error is coming from and I showed him the line where it most likely does. How does it not answer the question?